# C# to Excel, replace key letters with key word

Tags: c#

When data is sent to Excel the user will enter "I" to be replaced with Included, "EV" for Evaluation or "EX" for Existing in a certain textbox. I am successful with coding one but how can I combine them to look for any of the three in one statement? My existing line of code below and the example of what I am looking for is below that.

```
    worksheet.Cells[defaultRow, "H"].Replace("I", "Included"); //working

    worksheet.Cells[defaultRow, "H"].Replace("I", "Included")("EV", "Evaluation")("EX", "Existing"); //not working
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `I`, `EX` and `EV` is the only content which can be placed in this cell, you can do the following:

```
switch (worksheet.Cells[defaultRow,"H"].Value2.ToString())
{
    case "I":
        worksheet.Cells[defaultRow,"H"].Value2 = "Included";
        break;
    case "EV":
        worksheet.Cells[defaultRow,"H"].Value2 = "Evaluation";
        break;
    case "EX":
        worksheet.Cells[defaultRow,"H"].Value2 = "Excluded";
        break;
    default:
        worksheet.Cells[defaultRow,"H"].Value2 = "Wrong input";
}
```

It will prevent wrong output and provide means to validate input.
If you use `Replace` and a user inputs `"IIIIIII"`, then it will become: `"IncludedIncludedIncludedIncludedIncluded..."`.

Moreover, if you have more than 10 options, will you chain 10 `Replace` calls? Using a `switch` looks better for me.

Comment: Ooooh, this works as well because I do need to validate. The field will have a default price from the database but the user can change the price or enter the above mentioned I, EV OR EX. If it is anything other than those options or a price then I actually need to throw up a message to make the corrections when the button is pressed to transfer the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
worksheet.Cells[defaultRow, "H"].Replace("I", "Included").Replace("EV", "Evaluation").Replace("EX", "Existing");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: worksheet.Cells[,] is string and worksheet.Cells[].Replace(old,new) is string